# Akka : How to assign an Actor an alias path

Tags: java, akka, reactive-programming, actor

I am working on a POC trying to implement a device server using Akka Java. For the same I was wondering how can I create an alias path like symbolic link to an Actor after the actor is created.

I was reading this article (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html)

> Blockquote As in some real file-systems there also are “symbolic links”, i.e. one actor may be reachable using more than one path, where all but one involve some translation which decouples part of the path from the actor’s actual supervision ancestor line; these specialities are described in the sub-sections to follow.

If I can get some example that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

That section of the docs is actually a little misleading: the fact that for some cases am actor may have multiple paths is only an implementation detail, it does not mean that aliases can be created deliberately. In particular, remote deployment is currently the only way this can happen.

So the short answer is: in practice it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for answering Roland, I've made it a ticket to improve the docs too: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20773

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Roland. So, If I want to access an actor do I need to know each sub-actor the entire path?

Comment: Also,  I am currently accessing the actor by using /user/parent1-actor*/parent2-actor*/.../actor-1234 and it works. But, when I tried /user/*/actor-1234 it does not work. Am I correct or am I missing something? Also, at the time when I want this actor "actor-1234" I have the unique identifier "1234" what are the different ways I can access this actor.

Comment: More precisely: if you want to communicate with an actor you should have its ActorRef. Using ActorSelection in this fashion is a smell, actors are not a filesystem—this is a lesson we also needed to learn when building Akka. The reason is that you will run into conflicts between your file structure and the supervision hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could create an actor like this on the alias path and point it to the actual actor:

```
class SymLink( pointer: ActorRef ) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case e => pointer forward e
  }
}
```

Not sure if this helps in your situation though.